# zk: binding data in combobox

Tags: combobox, zk

i have entity FDataTableColumn which has field referenceFieldId which is long type and refs onto id of such column. On the create page i have combobox with list of all columns, i want to chose one and to put its id value to my referenceFieldId.
this is my combobox:

```
<combobox model="@load(fdtcm.fDataTableColumns)"  selectedItem="@bind(fdtcm.fDataTableColumn.referenceFieldId)" width="50%">
                                <template name="model">
                                    <comboitem label="@load(each.table.tableName.concat('.').concat(each.tableField))" value="@bind(each.id)"/>
                                </template>
                            </combobox>
```

Looks like it's all good but i got this exception

```
Cannot convert FDataTableColumn{id=6, type=STRING, tableField='EMAIL'} of type class ru.webvane.framework.metadata.entity.FDataTableColumn to class java.lang.Long at [file:/E:/apache-tomcat-7.0.28%20(64)/webapps/fw/fw/importData/dataTableColumn/input.zul, line:86]
```

i understand that my combo is trying to save the whole object to referenceFieldId, but why ? because i'm trying to save object's id

```
value="@bind(each.id)"
```

can anyone help me or explain what i'm doing wrong. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SergeBud,

It is possible to do so but as askkuber already points out, the class of what's inside the combobox is the class what will be saved.

Now you just have to implement [your own custom converter](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/MVVM/Data_Binding/Converter#Use_Custom_Converter) :

then it should the zul be like :

```
selectedItem="@bind(fdtcm.fDataTableColumn.referenceFieldId) @converter(fdtcm.myConverter)"
```

Comment: thanks, i solved my problem with @Transient field in entity class.

Answer (score 0):

You can check following code which written by me [zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/05/zk-combobox-with-selectoption.html](http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/05/zk-combobox-with-selectoption.html) this will explain you the right way to use Combobox.

**EDIT :-**

Then you can check this link [Combobox](http://emrpms.blogspot.in/2014/01/zk-mvvm-combo-box-value-converter.html) this will help you

Look **selectedItem** should be object of the class **FDataTableColumn** but in you case you refer it as  **id** which is **Long** it could be a reason of the exception make changes in your code.

Comment: i saw this code before. you are using extra class SelectOption to select item. But ( if i understand right ) combobox is able to select objects without any new classes, i meaning thad if i want to save from list of classes TestClass to field typeof TestClass, there is no need to create new class for selection, it's enough only combobox. That's why i think, that i can choose not just whole object from list, but only field i need, and do this without new classes

Comment: i wrote about combobox with converters. is it legal to use them ? i wrote, that if you override defualt converter, it would be used for other comboboxes too and it would be type mismatch or different kind of exception?

in my case i'm trying to put Long into Long 

<comboitem label="@load(each.table.tableName.concat('.').concat(each.tableField))" value="@bind(each.id)"/>

look ! i'm binding not the whole object but its id field, but it doesn't work (((

Comment: Try to bind class in selectitem..selecteditem work for a object of List not a single variable.

Comment: FYI read this To save or restore selected item we should bind **selectedItem to a property whose type equals the object of the Model.** In our example, we should bind "selectedItem" to an Item object.